# How to get reversed enumerate in python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list with such structure:

```
[(key1, val1), (key2, val2), ...]
```

And I want to iterate over it getting key and the index of item on each step. In reverse order.

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
for index, key in reversed(list(enumerate(map(lambda x: x[0], data)))):
    print index, key
```

It works perfectly, but I'm just worrying if it's a properly way to do. Can there is be a better solution?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: then the numbers go *up*, not down. The last element is numbered 0, etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately, it's not the same, because indexes will not be reversed.

Comment: Using `operator.itemgetter(0)` in place of the lambda will be faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`enumerate()` cannot count down, only up. Use a [`itertools.count()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) instead:

```
from itertools import izip, count

for index, item in izip(count(len(data) - 1, -1), reversed(data)):
```

This produces a count starting at the length (minus 1), then counting down as you go along the reversed sequence.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, count
>>> data = ('spam', 'ham', 'eggs', 'monty')
>>> for index, item in izip(count(len(data) - 1, -1), reversed(data)):
...     print index, item
... 
3 monty
2 eggs
1 ham
0 spam
```

Comment: Looks like the best solution right there, but I didn't get why are you using itertools.count instead of simple xrange?

Comment: @asnelzin: is `xrange()` simpler? I find `count()` to be simpler; I only have to give it 2 arguments, not 3. We don't have to worry about the end value here, as it is the finite `data` sequence that ends the loop.

Comment: And some addition: `reversed()` doesn't work with generators. So the second example will not work.

Comment: @asnelzin: ick, you are correct. `map()` or a list comprehension it is then, or unpack *after* reversing. Removed the incorrect part.

Comment: @martineau: heh, well spotted. Corrected now. This comment will self-destruct in 30.. 29..

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://christophe-simonis-at-tiny.blogspot.com/2008/08/python-reverse-enumerate.html) is interesting article about this problem. The following solution is proposed:

```
from itertools import izip
reverse_enumerate = lambda l: izip(xrange(len(l)-1, -1, -1), reversed(l))
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> it = reverse_enumerate(a)
>>> it.next()
(2, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]

for n,k in reversed([(i,k[0]) for i, k in enumerate(list)]):
    print n,k
```

You should use a dict instead of list with key/values, that what they are for.

edit: That should work.

Comment: The `i` values are incorrect. Result should be `b 1` and `a 0`

Comment: Unless it's only the order of the indices from `enumerate` that matter, a `dict` (which is unordered) doesn't make a lot of sense here.

Comment: A OrderedDict[ https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict ] might be best them.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these 2 suffice if the performance is not absolutely crucial.

```
sorted(enumerate(data), reverse=True)

reversed(list(enumerate(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

enumerate() on the reverse slice will work:

```
for i, x in enumerate(data[::-1]):
    print(len(data)-1-i, x[0])
```

This will create least temp objects: just one enumerate() object, and one slice() object.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own enumerate:

```
def enumerate_in_reverse(sequence):
    if not sequence:
        return
    for i in range(len(sequence) - 1, -1, -1):
        yield i, sequence[i]
```